# .ebextensions .config file not working on Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to change this setting on my AutoScaling group in my Beanstalk environment:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html

I'm doing exactly like the example shows, but it just doesn't work. Nothing happens.

The file content:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Properties:
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
```

The structure:

```
my_project/
  .ebextensions/
      autoscaling.config
  src/
  ...
```

Is there any log where I can check if the file is even being read or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem. I'm using Green/Blue environments to deploy my application, so in the process of uploading new changes to the environment they were being made to the Green Env that was being terminated after.

In order for the new config to work I had to rebuild the Blue env.

From now on all the new deploys will have the new config.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `eb deploy` to deploy your changed code, it will not deploy your local code, but your last git commit.

You can try to find something in the logs in `/var/log`, for example in eb-engine.log or messages, or even in the system logs (`$ journalctl`), if you configured to be able to ssh into the machine.

You can also use the web console to download the logs (like [this demo link](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=eu-central-1#/environment/logs?applicationName=Foo&environmentId=Bar)).

If you don't find something, can you give some more information about the platform (java, node.js, python) and the way you are deploying?

Bye,

Dirk